# How to Show Different Information to your authors/contributers

Tags: hooks, post-status

One of the nice tricks that WordPress admins who have a number of authors/contributors could do to help them in writing content is to share with them relevant information based on where they are in the writing process.

[image]

Using the code below, you can display helpful information above the back-end editors. This can be: guidelines, pre-publish checklist, certain codes or formatting tips, a video, or even a simple visual process just telling them at what stage of the publishing process they are at and how to proceed to the next one.

Of course, this depends largely on your writing or editorial process, but basically, if you use WordPress built-in or custom post statuses with your writers, this trick can be very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will use the admin_notices hook to display the information on top of the editor.

**First, a very basic example**

```
function educadme_fill_then_save_admin_notice(){
     global $pagenow;
     if ( $pagenow == 'post.php' || $pagenow == 'post-new.php' ) {

         echo '<div class="alert">
               <p>This is some text. You can embed images, videos, whatever, and they will display on top of the editing or new post page</p>

               </div>'

        }
}
add_action('admin_notices', 'educadme_fill_then_save_admin_notice');
```

The above can be used to display relevant information on top of the editor if the user is writing a new post or editing an existing one.

**More dynamic/changing information**

So what if you wanted to show relevant information that is related to where they are in the process? Well, in this case, we can add the post status into the IF like this:

```
function educadme_fill_then_save_admin_notice(){
     global $pagenow;
     $post_status = get_post_status();

     if ( $post_status =='assigned' AND $pagenow == 'post.php' ) {

         echo '<div class="alert">
               <p>This is some text. You can embed images, videos, whatever, and they will display on top of the editing or new post page</p>

               </div>'

        }
}
add_action('admin_notices', 'educadme_fill_then_save_admin_notice');
```

In the above example, I am showing the information only if the post is being edited and it has the post status 'assigned'.

If you plan to use, like I am going to, remember to change the name of the function in the function itself and the hook. Also change the post status to what you are using. If you want to use custom statuses for posts, you can either write a code to add them or use a plugin like EditFlow which I am using, to add post statuses.

I hope these codes are of use to someone! I am definitely going to add a visual process to explain to contributors where they are in the process and how they can proceed.

If you have any suggestions or improvements, please share! I am not a coder but I like to experiment and test stuff.